# All possible combinations of boolean variables

Tags: c#, algorithm, boolean

I'm trying to find an algorithm that will allow me to do the following:
Imagine I have 10 boolean variables, and I want to try every combination, since my goal is to find ANY combination which will give as a result to one of my methods true (This method has lots of restrictions, which is why I want to test every possible combinations, and if there are no combinations that will solve the problem, then I want to notify the user this).
I hope it is understandable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally came up with a more efficient method: Using binary numbers:
Let's say I want to test all possible boolean combinations out of 8 variables:
If I pick do the following I'll get to test every combination:

```
public string CombinationFinder()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 ^ 8; i++)
    {
        String ans = Convert.ToInt32(i, 2).ToString();
        if (myMethod(ans))
        {
            return ans;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This will go from 0 to 255, which in binary means going from 00000000 to 11111111
where each digit take the value 0 or 1, which can be represented as boolean. In this example if there's no combination found the method will return null.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (1 << 10); i++)
{
    bool b1 = (i & (1 << 0)) != 0;
    bool b2 = (i & (1 << 1)) != 0;
    bool b3 = (i & (1 << 2)) != 0;
    bool b4 = (i & (1 << 3)) != 0;
    ...

    if (MyMethod(b1, b2, b3, b4, ...))
    {
        // Found a combination for which MyMethod returns true
    }
}
```

You can, of course, also use LINQ:

```
var result = from b1 in new[] { false, true }
             from b2 in new[] { false, true }
             from b3 in new[] { false, true }
             from b4 in new[] { false, true }
             ...
             where MyMethod(b1, b2, b3, b4, ...)
             select new { b1, b2, b3, b4, ... };
```

Comment: I'm going to bed, it's almost 3 AM and I have to get up early, will let you know tomorrow, but from what I see I think it might work! :) thanks

Comment: Is there any way this could be applied but to a number of X variables (meaning I do not know how many booleans I'm gonna have, they depend on what the user chooses).
I'm not really familiar with the syntaxys, that's why I'm asking :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but waclock's answer doesn't compile (there's no exponent operator in C#). dtb's answer gets 99% of the way there, but doesn't handle unknown number of booleans, which is what this answer provides:

```
var props = typeof(TypeWithBooleans).GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool)).ToArray();

for (var i = 0; i < (1 << props.Length); ++i)
{
    var combination = Enumerable.Range(0, props.Length).Select(j => (i & (1 << j)) != 0).ToArray();
    if (MyMethod(combination)) {
        // handle match
    };
}
```

This assumes that all the booleans you care about are confined to a single class/struct, and that `MyMethod` uses a params array.

Answer (score 0):

define a class like this:

```
class Bint
{
  int num;
  public bool this[int num]
  {
    get {return num << n & 0x1 == 1;}
  }
  public int Num
  {
    get {return num;}
    set {num = value;}
  }
}
```

and iterate through the numbers:

```
Bint n = new Bint();
for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2,10); i++)
{
 n.Num = i;
 f(n[0],n[1]...);
}
```